# Groupby.sum() giving ValueError: overflow in timedelta operation

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum, timedelta

I am looking for a solution to a conversion involving Timedeltas. Here are the min and max values for a feature:

```
timeseries['column'].min()
timeseries['column'].max()
```

gives

```
Timedelta('0 days 11:05:14')
Timedelta('23743 days 06:25:08')
```

respectively.

How can I do the following whilst retaining time resolution:

```
summed = timeseries.groupby('another column')['column1'].sum()
```

without giving

```
ValueError: overflow in timedelta operation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found similar questions but don't think they really address the problem properly. Here is a better solution:

```
import datetime
```

Convert the series in to seconds:

```
timeseries['column'] = timeseries['column'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Now:

```
summed = timeseries.groupby('another column')['column1'].sum()
```

Convert back to timedelta:

```
summed['column'].fillna(0).apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(seconds=x))
```